# Read Price from Dex and show in the page

Tags: api

Is there a API or anyway how i can read the price for a crypto currencys from different Dex like uniswap? i want to show a list in my page with the price for a crypto currency, how much it cost there at the different Dex sites.

Comment: [Recommendations](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for resources like API's are considered off-topic here. You might be able to ask this over at the [Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange site, but would recommend reviewing their [Help](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page as to what's considered on-topic there.